# Erro ao Clonar Repositório GitHub

Tags: github

Estou tentando inicializar o repositório já existente que tenho GitHub porém quando o clono, da tudo certo.

```
**Cloning into 'ecommerce'...
remote: Counting objects: 1802, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (53/53), done.
remote: Total 1802 (delta 44), reused 72 (delta 34), pack-reused 1710
Receiving objects: 100% (1802/1802), 8.33 MiB | 1.39 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (449/449), done.**
```

Mas quando abro o terminal na pasta clonada e dou um git status, dá um erro como se meu repositório estivesse vazio, já pesquisei comandos e tudo porém não está dando certo com nenhum.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: ***Your branch is up to date***, não é um erro, é uma mensagem dizendo que você não possui nenhuma alteração para *commitar* e que o repositório está atualizado perante o *origin*.

Comment: Realmente, tem razão, porém queria desfazer um commit, no repositório, porém fiz alguma coisa errada tentando desfazer, e acabei apagando da minha máquina local e clonando o repositório, porém estava dando o mesmo erro, mas após da um commit voltou ao normal, obrigado!